# Warped Rotors again

Tags: discussion

The prevailing sentiment in [this thread](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/31909/warped-disc-rotors-again/38368#38368) goes directly against the facts and accepted answer in [this thread](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11612/what-causes-brakes-to-pulsate-right-after-rotor-and-pad-replacement/11632#11632).

Indeed, the "correct" (or at least, more correct) answer (of mine) is being downvoted into oblivion.

I'm not sure what to do about this, other than call attention to it here. Suggestions?

Comment: I wouldn't call -2 "obliviion" but I get your point. Unfortunately, there isn't much which can be done with it from my vantage point. People can vote as they are going to vote, even if the supplied evidence is right/wrong. As you can tell by @DucatiKiller 's comment on the linked content, we both agree with you. There are actually plenty of answers running around which are accepted and agree with what you're saying.

Comment: Have a +1 and stop whining (grin). Good info there.. never knew warped rotors were a myth... As Bob said, You should hang out in the pitstop if you have time... We'd love the company.

Comment: Thank you. It appears time (and you guyz) have healed all wounds.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest bringing this up in the chat rather than in meta. That's a place with real discussions going all the time. Traffic in meta can be thin.

Comment: I would love to, but during work hours it has to be quick drop in and run. Evenings family takes precedence... but I will try chat when I find the time.

Answer (score 5):

I've been on both sides of this type of argument. Sometimes everybody believes in notions you KNOW are untrue, and sometimes somebody shows up and declares something you've always thought to be true to be untrue. I call this the "Santa Claus" effect.

You've done all you can do, you've put your information out there. Let people believe what they will. :)